# Nesting page components inside Router or Page components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

We have a react project where we have layout components, child layout components and some page components.

```
<Layout1 />
<Layout2 />
 <ChildLayout1>
 <ChildLayout2>
   <Component1/> 
   <Component2> 
   <Component3>
```

And we have lets say 6 different pages , all made of these components. My question is about where to do nesting for the project, in router (by nesting route components) or in seperate page components. In case you didn't get my question, here are both scenarios seperately.

Scenario 1 : nesting in react-router

```
<Router>
    <Route component={Layout1}>
        <Route component={ChildLayout1}>
            <Route path="page1" component={Component1} />
            <Route path="page2" component={Component2} />
        </Route>
        <Route component={ChildLayout2}>
           <Route path="page3" component={Component2} />
           <Route path="page4" component={Component3} />
        </Route> 
    </Route>
    <Route component={Layout1}>
        <Route component={ChildLayout1}>
            <Route path="page5" component={Component1} />
            <Route path="page6" component={Component2} />
        </Route> 
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Scenario 2 : nesting in page components and mounting in Route components

```
// for all pages do the same as below 
// page1.jsx

<Layout1>
    <ChildLayout1>
        <Component1 />
        <Component2 />
    <ChildLayout1 />
<Layout1 />

// routes.jsx

<Router>
    <Route path="page1" component={Page1} />
    <Route path="page2" component={Page2} />
    <Route path="page3" component={Page3} />
    <Route path="page4" component={Page4} />
    <Route path="page5" component={Page5} />
    <Route path="page6" component={Page6} />
</Router>
```

**What are the benefits of one way over another ?** From a performance point of view, is there any differences or is it only the ease of coding coders may prefer one over another.